# Node.js websocket error “Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL”

Tags: networking, server, nodejs

Application work fine on localhost but when it's connected to the server, it is giving the next error.

```
 Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
 at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
 at Server._listen2 (net.js:1023:19)
 at listen (net.js:1064:10)
 at net.js:1146:9
 at dns.js:72:18
 at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
 at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
 at startup (node.js:119:16)
 at node.js:906:3
```

I connect server through port 22 but my app is connecting the server on port 80.

I ran `netstat -tulpn | grep 22` and result is:

```
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      683/sshd
 tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      683/sshd
```

But if I run `netstat -tulpn | grep 80` nothing is displayed.

Is this server fault? [This](https://github.com/totaljs/examples/tree/master/angularjs-websocket) is the source.

Comment: What do you mean with "when it's connected to the server"? What are you changing to go from localhost to "server"? I guess that you cannot run it on port 80 because it is already used (don't you have apache, nginx or something else there?) or either you don't have privileges.

Comment: @lucio - no i have dedicated ubuntu server .i connect server with using putty.and its port 22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you don't have privileges to operate on port 80. Try the following:

1. Change the value of `default-port` from `8000` to `3000`
2. Redirect traffic in port 80 to 3000 using iptables

   ```
   iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
   ```